# Android listview toggle image by click, changes more than one image

Tags: android, image, listview

I have a listview and on click I try to change an arrow image inside my listview adapter row.
This works fine, but I have the problem, that not only a single image changes. A few rows above and below the arrow images also change.

It changes the images in every 6th row.

the code for my onClick event is this:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View view, int position, long id) {


    if (row != null) 
    {
         ImageView PfeilImage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
         PfeilImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.pfeil);
    }
     ImageView PfeilImage2 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
     PfeilImage2.setImageResource(R.drawable.pfeil_aktiv);

     row = view;
     getInfoById(position);
     }
  });
```

It would be nice if someone could help me with that problem.

thanks in advance
Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it, many thanks.

in my Adapter Class I made a new int variable "myClickedPosition".

In my click event I set this variable and after this I set notifyDataSetInvalid to redraw the listview:

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> theAdapter,View view, int position, long id) {
  LazyAdapter mAdapter = (LazyAdapter) theAdapter.getAdapter();
  mAdapter.myClickedPosition=position;
  mAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
  getInfoById(position);

  }
 });
```

and in my getView function I check the clicked position:

```
 if(myClickedPosition == position)
 {
   PfeilIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.pfeil_aktiv);
 } else {
   PfeilIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.pfeil);
 }
```

Now all is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

That's actually normal for how the ListView is setup since it is designed to not re-inflate Views, but instead re-use them; which is why you can't just change the image, you need to change the data it's pointing to.

The solution to this, inside your Adapter's getView() method, is to check the data and set the background image based on that.

You may want to create a new Class to hold your current data and the new image to use holder. ie.

```
Class ListViewItem
  -int imageToUse
  -Object whateverDataYouWereOriginallyUsing
```

and then set the image for that view based on ListViewItem.get(position).imageToUse

Now, when you're actually changing the data based on a user click, you'll need to call notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter so that it will re-evaluate the UI based on the new DataSet and your getView() method

Comment: You just need to point the getView() method at the correct data source; not just update the image, the data itself has to change